# Should aspnetdb objects be generated in the application database or in their own separate database?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, aspnetdb

I am using MVC 4 and SQL Server with my application database. I want to add user authentication where the user will have extra fields when registering *(e.g. address, telephone, etc...)*. What is the correct way to accomplish this?

I have considered the following options:

1. Generate a separate `aspnetdb` db and authenticate against it, alter the user columns in it and use the main application db after authentication, presumably using sessions to store user info.
2. Don't create a `aspnetdb`, but add the `aspnetdb` tables to the application db and add additional fields to the relevant generated table.
3. As #2 above, but create a separate user table in the application db and join the relevant `aspnetdb` on an existing table.

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET MVC 4 uses the SimpleMemebrship provider out of the box. You could add custom fields to the UserProfile table. Here's a [`step-by-step article`](http://blog.longle.net/2012/09/25/seeding-users-and-roles-with-mvc4-simplemembershipprovider-simpleroleprovider-ef5-codefirst-and-custom-user-properties/) explaining how you could achieve that.